# Cannot remove the styling of the input field in jquery mobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

**HTML:**

```
My name is
<input type="text" class="amountBox" value="sam" readonly />
```

**CSS:**

```
.amountBox[readonly] {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none; /*{b-active-background-color}*/
       -moz-box-shadow: none; /*{b-active-background-color}*/
            box-shadow: none; /*{b-active-background-color}*/
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

i cannot remove whats around it, be it the border or shadow,i cant remove it.I dont want any styling..But no way i can achieve it.any help?

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/B2qfL/5/

Comment: I cannot find .amountBox[readonly] in your JSfiddle CSS column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `data-role="none"` attribute to elements you don't want to be styled by JQM.

```
<input type=text data-role=none />
```